# How to show local notifications when app is closed in Flutter on Android device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I have some troubles with showing sheduled local notifications in Flutter on Android device. It works when app is opened, but when app is closed notifications don't show.
There is NotificationManager class that shows notifications:

```dart
class NotificationManager {

  static final NotificationManager _instance = NotificationManager._internal();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  NotificationManager._internal();

  factory NotificationManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings androidSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher");

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidSettings,
    );

    initializeTimeZones();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(int id, String title, String body, int seconds) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        TZDateTime.now(local).add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
        _defaultDetails(),
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true
    );
  }

  NotificationDetails _defaultDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'main_channel',
        "Main Channel",
        channelDescription: "Main Channel",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.max,
        icon: "@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher"
      )
    );
  }
  
}
```

There is how I use it in the main.dart:

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationManager().init();
  NotificationManager().showNotification(1, "Aboba", "Feed aboba", 10);
  runApp(Application());
}
```

So if I don't close app, it works.
When I close app, notification doesn't show.
How can I fix that?

P.S. There is AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found solution to this problem. Just use [Workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Workmanager().initialize(callback);
  Workmanager().registerOneOffTask("uniqueName", "taskName");
  runApp(Application());
}

void callback() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
    NotificationManager().init();
    NotificationManager().showNotification(
        id: 1,
        title: "Aboba",
        body: "Feed aboba",
        delaySeconds: 100);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```